# How to hide paragraph marks in OpenOffice.org Writer?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

How do I remove the blue P-marks that indicate paragraphs from my documents when working?

I have looked under the 'Tools' menu but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Which “blue P-marks” in which context, and in which version of MS Word? Do you actually mean the “¶” marks (which normally appear in black)?

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what program you are using, but it's non-printing character, at least that's what is is named in  "Open Office Writer".

In that program, go to "View" and toggle "non-printing characters".

Comment: In case if you are using LibreOffice Writer: [Hide Nonprinting characters](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Nonprinting_Characters)

Answer (score 2):

For Libreofice writer  use Ctrl+F10 since it does Not have a backwards P in the tool bar like Openoffice. You can also see this in the View drop down menu under "Formatting Marks" and just click to toggle it off/on

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle off the backwards P symbol in the paragraph box:
[image]